# WIX JSON Payload mapping/input into text input element

Tags: javascript, java, json, payload, velo

I'm working on an integration between Wix and PipeDrive API.  My GET requests are successful and returning a payload - but I am trying to figure out how to process that payload and insert fields from the payload into a wix text input element.

Can anyone provide me an example of how to process data from the payload and insert it into a text input?

Below is an example of the payload I am getting in response:

[Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SzU9.png)

Here is an example of my backend code:
[Backend Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUkA6.png)

Here is an example of my successful GET code:
[GET request page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr5QB.png)